# android-ndk not able to build oracle bekerely database

Tags: android, oracle, android-ndk

I am trying to build Android JDBC Driver of Oracle Berkeley DB for the replacement of SQLite using android-ndk.

Oracle Berkeley DB Reference Link:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_05/html/installation/BDB_Installation.pdf

Go to **Page No. 21**

I am facing below error while following building:

```
    make: Entering directory `/usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni'
[armeabi] Compile arm    : db_archive <= db_archive.c
In file included from /usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../src/dbinc/mutex_int.h:12:0,
                 from /usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../src/dbinc/mutex.h:15,
                 from /usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../build_android/db_int.h:1216,
                 from /usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../util/db_archive.c:11:
/usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../src/dbinc/atomic.h: In function '__atomic_compare_exchange_int':
/usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../src/dbinc/atomic.h:155:2: warning: implicit declaration of function '__atomic_compare_exchange_n' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
/usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../src/dbinc/atomic.h:156:17: error: '__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST' undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../src/dbinc/atomic.h:156:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../util/db_archive.c: In function 'main':
/usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni/../../../util/db_archive.c:33:24: warning: variable 'verbose' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
make: *** [/usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/obj/local/armeabi/objs/db_archive/__/__/__/util/db_archive.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/usr/local/durgesh_oracle/db-6.2.23/build_android/jdbc/jni'
```

Comment: you need `stdatomic.h` header file?

Comment: @pskink Thanks mate. i followed only steps which are described in that doc. do you from where we can get? and in which location we need to put to build success?

Comment: @pskink thanks. in which location of  db-6.2.23 folder i need to put this file ?

Comment: @pskink can you please give your feedback if you have?